# Combine two y axes in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataset

**This is what I am doing**

```
b<- read.table("file_name.out")
EXP <- 2
names(b) <- paste("name_",1:30)
gg2 <- subset((aggregate(cbind(name_4)~name_1+name_2+name_3,b, FUN=mean)),(aggregate(cbind(name_4)~name_1+name_2+name_3,b, FUN=mean))$name_1 == c(1:EXP))
plot_exp <- 
  function(i){
    dat <- subset(gg2,name_1 == i )
    ggplot(dat,aes(x=name_3, y=name_4, fill = name_2)) + 
      geom_point(aes(color = name_2),size = 3) + geom_smooth(stat= "smooth" , alpha = I(0.01))
  }
ll <- lapply(seq_len(EXP), plot_exp)
do.call(grid.arrange,  ll)
```

The output of this is two graphs one below the other.

--I want to have a distinct Y-axes for both but a single x-axis.

--Also I want to name the two graphs distinctly here for ex: EXP1, EXP2

--And I want to have distinct color for distinct name_2 columns (As you can see the plots     are plotted for all the name_2 distinct entries)

--Again please help in naming the legends based on name_2 column, and also how to change the x and y axes names externally means outside the ggplot command once set.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a lot of sub questions inside of one question. It's best to isolate your problems. I'll address the ones I can understand.

I'm not sure you want separate plots. It seems like a `factet_grid` would b e a good choice for your first concern. I've also added a `labeller=` to label the slides "EXP1" and "EXP2". Also if you want treat name_2 as a categorical variable, you should convert it to a factor. If you want a line for each name_2 value, it's probably better to use `geom_line` than the `geom_point/geom_smooth` combo

```
gg2$name_2<-factor(gg2$name_2)

ggplot(gg2,aes(x=name_3, y=name_4, fill = name_2)) + 
   geom_line(aes(color = name_2),size = 1) + 
   facet_grid(name_1~., labeller=function(x,y) {paste0("EXP",y)})
```

[image: ggplot output]

Comment: That is very helpful thank you. One more thing I desperately want to have is different color for all all name_2 values. as you can see the color differentiation between individual name_2 plot is difficult. Is it possible to have different colors based on name_2 values ? or just a single color variation like the above is all that is there?

Comment: in the dataset I have 9 different values of name_2 for 1:9 and each value is plotted against name_3 as you can see. Now its easy to differentiate if I have different colors to represent different scatter curves of name_2.

Comment: Sound like you want to treat name_2 as categorical. You should change it to a factor. Do that with `gg2$name_2<-factor(gg2$name_2)`. I'm i'n not sure you really want points here. Seems like you want lines for each name_2. Just do `geom_line(aes(color = name_2),size = 1)` rather than `geom_point` and `geom_smooth`. But really, your points are so stacked up on top of each other you're not going to see a difference.

Comment: Yeah the difference between each set of values for name_2 is soo stacked the graph doesnt even look like a point graph. Is there something I can do to increase the aspect ratio to view the scattering of each name_2 plots somewhat clearly if not too much? otherwise is there something of a zoom option which I can provide (other than coord_cartesian, i mean just like a picture view)?